# Custom font no being applyed on CSS

Tags: css, fonts

Could someone tell me what's wrong here..? I've checked it many times and can not find the problem. Page always loads with Impact instead of Corbert font.

Also, when I check what is happening trough Firebug, 'corbert' name displays grey, and when hovering it, the miniature that Firebug shows as a font demo, is not Corvert, like if it did not find the files:

[image: captcha32]

CSS code (I have also tried setting the first one to .eot)

```
@font-face {
font-family: ‘corbert’;
   src: url('corbert-regular.ttf');
   src: url('corbert-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('corbert-regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('corbert-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('corbert-regular.svg#adlerRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }

body {
    overflow-x: hidden; height:100%; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; font-family:'corbert',Fallback, impact;
}
```

Here you have a screen of the folder with linked fonts:
[image: captcha]

Comment: try to change the path's to something like this: `../fonts/corbert-regular.ttf`

Comment: Ok i'll try but at first fonts were on fonts/ but i changed it to root to try to find the problem.

Comment: what browser are you testing in? there are a few hacks that need to be applied to your @font-face to make it work all across the board

Comment: did you apply the `..` at the beginning? My bad, you have no separated css folder, so there is no need to go back.

Comment: shouldn't need  `..`  - they're all in the same dir

Comment: yes, that should not be needed.... anyway i've tried all ways (on root, on /fonts with .. and on /fonts without ..)

Comment: try `font-family:font` instead of `font-family:'font'`

Comment: @danyamachine i am testiong on chrome, firefox and all the same:impact. I am about to try your solution

Comment: Solved. thank you but i have re-downloaded fonts and now works, files must have had some kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typographic apostrophes around the font name, so the name is actually `‘corbert’` rather than `corbert`.

Use regular apostrophes:

```
font-family: 'corbert';
```

Also, is the SVG name of the font really `adlerRegular`, and not something like `corbertRegular`?

Comment: oh........... I re-downloadede everything and re-typed and now it works. you are right, that was the error for sure. Thenk you.

Answer (score 1):

my fool proof `@font-face` code (taken from someone else's excruciating troubleshooting, but I can't remember who...):

> @font-face {
>         font-family: 'fontname';
>
> ```
>   src: url('fonts/fontname.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
>   src: url('fonts/fontname.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
>          url('fonts/fontname.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
>          url('fonts/fontname.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
>          url('fonts/fontname.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
>     }
> ```

note that there are two `src` and there are `#` on a couple of lines. 
and the order seems to matter quite a bit

[edit: it's from [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)]

Comment: thank you but i have re-downloaded fonts and now works, files must have had some kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

I always refer to this blog post when I'm having trouble with custom fonts; [Bulletproof @font-face Syntax](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/).

In short, you should be using:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'corbert';
  src: url('corbert-regular.eot?') format('eot'), 
       url('corbert-regular.woff') format('woff'),      
       url('corbert-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: I've included the essential parts.